# Why is my smoke bright on the edges?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, smoke-simulation

I was doing some motion tracking and I implemented some smoke. Once I rendered the scene, there is this bright perimeter framing my smoke. I'm not sure if this is a bug or not but i would like to know how to remove it.[image]

Comment: What format did you render smoke in to overlay on the footage ? This looks like a wrong treating of the alpha channel and it's best to render smoke  into OpenEXR (or maybe .tiff) to overlay later. Maybe related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44358/adding-cold-breath-effect-over-a-video

Comment: Please use the [edit] link and add more information to your question. How are you overlaying the image? What are your render setings? What format? etc.

Comment: It could be the blend mode or the alpha mask that is doing this.

Comment: Potentially related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67884/599, http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/38459/599, and http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/67346/599

Comment: It looks like there is a misplaced pre-division or wrong interpretation of a unassociated alpha image.
Easy to test: using the "convert premul" checkbox in the alpha over node should either mitigate or eliminate the problem. Hard to tell without more information (what cegaton asked above)

Comment: I've had this effect when placing a plane textured with an alpha layered image - my solution was to tick (or untick) the "Transparency" box under the plane's properties. (cube icon at top)  Objects behind the plane needed that box ticked/unticked also in some cases.  I wasn't using nodes in any of these cases.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is your issue, but you should give it a try :D

[image: check convert premul]

Comment: Please add more detail to the answer as text. Don't rely  on images only. Add a small explanation of what you are doing. Also if you are uploading images make sure that they are legible. It is impossible to read what node and options you are using.